# How to Save/store push notifications sent from Parse and print it out on any viewcontroller?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, push-notification, swift2, push

I have finished an application with push notification setup through Parse and it was successful, I have followed the doc of Parse to setup push notifications on swift 2.0 ,I can send push notifications. However, I need to add one important thing to the app, is how to store/save the push notification message received to the app and to print it in one/any viewcontrollers? And, of course, any new push notification would replace the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Save the notifications in a table on your server. Then when app is run, call web service and read notifications from that table